# Send kubernetes audit logs to multiple servers

Tags: logging, kubernetes, audit

How to send k8s audit logs to multiple servers/endpoints?
I tried to

- pass multiple `--audit-webhook-config-file` arguments to kube-apiserver
- add another cluster to the webhook config file

but these modifications are invalid and the kube-apiserver won't start up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to send audit logs to multiple servers using `kube-apiserver` arguments or configuration.

You have to deploy another service which mirrors incoming HTTP requests to multiple servers.

Using **nginx** [ngx_http_mirror_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_mirror_module.html):

```
location / {
    mirror /mirror;
    proxy_pass http://audit-server-1;
}

location = /mirror {
    internal;
    proxy_pass http://audit-server-2;
}
```

Using **gor** https://github.com/buger/goreplay

```
gor --input-tcp :8000 --output-http "http://audit-server-1"  --output-http "http://audit-server-1"
```